# SimpleDateFormatt gravar com campo vazio

Tags: jsp, servlet

Estou com dificuldades em gravar um campo vazio, pois está sendo formatado com o SimpleDateFormatt..

Ao gravar o console gera um erro

```
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

**Servlet**

```
    private void gravarProximo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");


        OrdemServico c = (OrdemServico) request.getSession().getAttribute("ordemServico"); 

                c.setDataOpen(sdf.parse(request.getParameter("dataOpen")));
                c.setDataClosed(sdf2.parse(request.getParameter("dataClosed")));
```

Alguem pode me ajudar em como fazer com que grave mesmo se o campo estiver vazio?

no banco de dados está sem not null...

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema não está na hora de salva no banco.

A exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""` diz respeito ao parse que você tenta fazer de uma `String` vazia.

É muito simples para resolver isso, basta verificar antes se a string é vazia:

```
private void gravarProximo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  try {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
      SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
      OrdemServico c = (OrdemServico) request.getSession().getAttribute("ordemServico"); 

      String dataOpen = request.getParameter("dataOpen");
      if(dataOpen != null && !dataOpen.isEmpty()){
           c.setDataOpen(sdf.parse(dataOpen));
      }
      String dataClosed = request.getParameter("dataClosed");
      if(dataClosed != null && dataClosed.isEmpty()){
           c.setDataClosed(sdf2.parse(dataClosed));
      }
```

Agora você poderá salvar seu objeto **OrdemServico** normalmente.